# Who is Ho in the Ho-Kalman algorithm?

Tags: math-history, control-theory, system-identification

It is mentioned in the following article

https://cacm.acm.org/news/210107-in-memoriam-rudolf-kalman-19302016/fulltext

that (with attribution which I suspect is wrong)

> He also worked with Yu-Chi Ho on the minimal realization problem, resulting in what came to be known as the Ho-Kálmán algorithm.

I know that Yu-Chi Ho did work with Kalman, but on Kalman-Ho-Narendra Theorem, for example, 
[Reference for Kalman-Ho-Narendra Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2564694/reference-for-kalman-ho-narendra-theorem)

On the other hand, in http://www.ece.uah.edu/PDFs/news/RT-sprsum2002.pdf, we can find the following mentioned by the mathematician R. W. Bass,

> During the years just before and after Kalman accepted a professorship at  Stanford  in  1964  he  published  algebraic  results  pertaining  to  realization theory, or modeling of linear input-output systems, which laid the groundwork for  a  stunning  discovery  by  his  graduate  student  B.  L.  Ho.    I  am  referring  to  Ho's doctoral dissertation's main result, published in 1966 as a joint paper with Kalman, which I regard as the most profound theorem pertaining to the Systems Identification  (ID)  problem.

the said paper (that I can trace) is "Effective Construction of Linear State-Variable Models from Input/Output Functions".

I know that Yu-Chi Ho is also called Larry Ho (at least according to wiki), and is a big shot in control theory. But he apparently is not Kalman's student, nor did he graduate from Stanford. The most recent news about B.L.Ho is in this article http://www.sontaglab.org/FTPDIR/kalman_students_article_2010.pdf
where only his name appeared.

I wonder who B.L. Ho is? (at least the full name) Am I right that he is not Yu-Chi Ho? Many thanks!

Comment: Note that you can use ```html```-similar markdown syntax to denote a link by writing ```[text](link)```

Comment: @ViktorGlombik, Sure! and many thanks! I know that it is not elegantly presented. But for this reference seeking post, the several links are pretty important IMO, and I cannot think of proper text for them. So I left them that way.

Comment: Bin-Lun Ho (ref: https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/2188860)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, B.L. Ho is Bin-Lun Ho, my father. I only recently found out his association with Rudolf Kahman as I was looking over copies of his doctoral dissertation. He went on after his time at Stanford to work in the hard disk drive industry.

Answer (score 0):

Yu-Chi Ho is professor with Harvard University, refer to
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yu-Chi_Ho

Luckily have several talks with him and he sometimes mentioned his experience worked with Kalman.

Comment: I think the question is who is B.L. Ho isn't it?